# Regex an Id tag from a string, Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex which will retrieve an Id from a given output.

***Output***

```
String output ="ieatenmpca06-neo4j-2              10.10.0.148:8301  alive   client  0.9.2  2         dc1";
```

***Regex To Find ID***

```
String NEO4J_ID = "ieatenmpca06-neo4j-\\d";
```

The given regex and output will return the result of `ieatenmpca06-neo4j-2` which is the answer I want.

However in the future, the Id will change, the start of the ID will be different `xxxxxxxx-neo4j-x`.

So I would like a regex which will find the id based on the `neo4j` section of the ID. The Id prefix (ieatenmpca06) and postfix number (1, 2, 3) will change but the `neo4j` will stay constant.

Comment: So you just need a regex to get the number after `-neo4j-` ... what is the problem ? using a capture group would be easier too. Just do it like [this](https://regex101.com/r/utprLe/1)

Comment: try this [`output = output.replaceAll("[^-]*-neo4j-(\\d+).*", "$1");`](https://ideone.com/j2npFZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple regex tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/utprLe/1) :

```
(\w+)-neo4j-(\d+)
```

> ieatenmpca06-neo4j-2

```
Match 1
Full match  0-20    `ieatenmpca06-neo4j-2`
Group 1.    0-12    `ieatenmpca06`
Group 2.    19-20   `2`
```

I will not provide the JAVA version of this, your question is not complete enough.

Comment: that worked great with the exact outcome I was hoping for.